# Remove blue frame from image with link

Tags: html, css, image, mobile, frame

i have some trouble with my html design. 
Every image that i link, have a blue frame with mobile view. I'm not talking about the border, but a blue opacity frame on the image when i click.

Here's the code : `<a href="Yan/index.html"><img class="charButton" src="img/yanButton.png"></a>`

Simple code, and i already add border:0 & outline:0 on the css file.

How can i hide this ?

[image: here the blue frame]

Comment: Please provide the code that you have right now.

Comment: try img{border:0} or img{border:none}

Comment: @Efbi I mean, both CSS and HTML to see the effect. Or a working example to see it better with your properties. You can create an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Oh thanks @HaroenViaene !! It's perfect it's works ! Thanks